# yii2 mpdf, not show google maps statics satellite view

Tags: php, google-maps, yii2, mpdf

I use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide for insert maps on pdf generated with `mpdf` library, with this code

```
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-19.0365720000,-65.2531240000&zoom=16&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&scale=2
&language=spanish&markers=color:red%7Clabel:Cliente%7C-19.0365720000,-65.2531240000&key=my-key">
```

but, I need satellite view, searched on documentation, and found the parameter to change

*maptype=satellite*

```
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-19.0365720000,-65.2531240000&zoom=16&size=200x200&maptype=satellite&scale=2&language=spanish&markers=color:red%7Clabel:Cliente%7C-19.0365720000,-65.2531240000&key=my-key">
```

I think is an bug of mpdf library, because when I use the code on a html file work fine,

Some idea about the error?

Comment: [Looks like a satellite map to me](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-19.0365720000,-65.2531240000&zoom=16&size=200x200&maptype=satellite&scale=2&language=spanish&markers=color:red%7Clabel:Cliente%7C-19.0365720000,-65.2531240000).  What error are you getting?

Comment: Not showed google maps statics satellite view inside pdf generated with mpdf, always showed roadmap, even when I used maptype=satellite

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question: I was using a non oficial repository of mpdf https://github.com/kartik-v/mpdf I review the github of the library I was using, and I read a new thing "Use the mpdf/mpdf repo instead", so, I downloaded the oficial library https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf and test my code and is ok!